# How to to get 'reason' in collector.on('end', ...)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
collector.on('collect', message => {
    if (message.content === 'bla bla bla') {
        message.channel.send(`bla bla bla`);
        collector.stop();
    }
})

collector.on('end', data => {
    if (!data.first()) {
        console.log('TimeOut');
    }
})
```

I want do some checking before it gets to the `collector.on('end' )` event. I want to check if the event ended because of the time out or the `.stop()`. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you can pass an optional parameter in `collector.stop()` which acts as the reason. The `collector.on('end', ...)` also includes this optional parameter. So by simply passing a string in the `.stop()` method you should be able to do what you need.

Below is some sample code, try it and let me know how it goes.

```js
collector.on('collect', message => {
  if (message.content === 'bla bla bla') {
    message.channel.send('bla bla bla');
    collector.stop('Collector stopped manually');
  }
});

collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
  if (reason && reason === 'Collector stopped manually') {
    console.log('Collector has been stopped manually');
  } else {
    console.log('Collector has NOT been stopped manually');
  }
});
```